# Issue with pruning binary tree in Python

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to prune a binary tree in Python by removing nodes with a value of 0 and no children. I have implemented two versions of the code, but the second implementation does not seem to be working as expected. Here are the two versions:

**First implementation:**

```
class Solution:
    def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

        root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left)
        root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right)

        if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None:
            return None

        return root
```

**Second implementation:**

```
class Solution:
    def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

        self.pruneTree(root.left)
        self.pruneTree(root.right)

        if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None:
            root = None
            return 

        return root
```

The first implementation seems to be working correctly and prunes the tree as expected. However, the second implementation does not work as I expect also I am specifically wondering why the line `root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left)` and `root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right)`

Comment: Are you asking why certain lines appear in your own code?

Comment: `root = None` only sets the local name, it doesn't alter anything in the tree. To alter the tree you need to have assignments to **attributes**, like `.left`. Since the second version has no such assignments, it is clear it will do nothing to your tree.

Comment: @trincot  Not in python at least. In other languages `root` could be some form of pointer/reference and setting it to `None` *could* change the tree, but in python it's really just a label to an object, if you reassign the label to `None` the only change in the object previously assigned that label is that the reference count is reduced

Comment: @Bakuriu, I know, but this question is specifically about Python code (and *their* code specifically). It's not C++.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two implementations is that the first implementation is modifying the tree in place by setting the left and right children of each node to the result of calling self.pruneTree on those children. The second implementation is not modifying the tree in place but instead is only modifying the local variable root. This means that when you set root = None, you are only changing the value of the local variable and not actually modifying the tree. To fix this issue, you can modify the second implementation to set the left and right children of each node to None instead of setting root to None. Here is an updated version of the second implementation:

```
class Solution:
    def pruneTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        if root is None:
            return None

    root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left)
    root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right)

    if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None:
        return None

    return root
```

Regarding your question about why we need to set root.left = self.pruneTree(root.left) and root.right = self.pruneTree(root.right) in the first implementation, this is because we need to recursively prune the left and right subtrees before we can prune the current node. By calling self.pruneTree(root.left) and self.pruneTree(root.right), we are recursively pruning the left and right subtrees. We then check if the current node should be pruned using if root.val == 0 and root.left is None and root.right is None. If it should be pruned, we return None. Otherwise, we return the current node.